# In Tcl, what is the equivalent of "set -e" in bash?

Tags: tcl

Is there a convenient way to specify in a Tcl script to immediately exit in case any error happens? Anything similar to `set -e` in bash?

**EDIT** I'm using a software that implements Tcl as its scripting language. If for example I run the package `parseSomeFile fname`, if the file `fname` does't exist, it reports it but the script execution continues. Is there a way that I stop the script there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually not needed; a command fails by throwing an error which makes the script exit with an informative message if not caught (well, depending on the host program: that's `tclsh`'s behavior). Still, if you need to *really* exit immediately, you can hurry things along by putting a trace on the global variable that collects error traces:

```
trace add variable ::errorInfo write {puts stderr $::errorInfo;exit 1;list}
```

(The `list` at the end just traps the trace arguments so that they get ignored.)

**Doing this is *not* recommended.** Existing Tcl code, including all packages you might be using, assumes that it can `catch` errors and do something to handle them.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. I wont use it often :), but sometimes it comes very handy.

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl, if you run into an error, the script will exit immediately unless you catch it. That means you don't need to specify the like of `set -e`.

#### Update

Ideally, `parseSomeFile` should have return an error, but looks like it does not. If you have control over it, fix it to return an error:

```
proc parseSomeFile {filename} {
    if {![file exists $filename]} {
        return -code error "ERROR: $filename does not exists"
    }
    # Do the parsing
    return 1
}

# Demo 1: parse existing file
parseSomeFile foo

# Demo 2: parse non-existing file
parseSomeFile bar
```

The second option is to check for file existence before calling `parseSomeFile`.